# IE8 Errors On chart.destroy()

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, highcharts

Under IE9, FF, Chrome this presents no problems. However, under IE8 we get:

> Object doesn't support this property or method

The offending line is:

```
chartMain.destroy();
```

We defined `chartMain` as:

```
chartMain = new Highcharts.Chart(optionsChartMain);
```

I can find no dangling commas or other js detritus that would make IE choke. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: what is contained in the chartMain object when you try to call the destroy() method?

Comment: Could you show this live? http://jsfiddle.net/GGQ2a/show/ - does it work for you? Maybe you don't have the latest version of Highcharts?

Comment: @PawełFus, that was it! I needed to explicitly name the container. The alias I was using (`chartMain`) was making IE8 fail. Make it an answer and I will check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working solution:

```
$('#container').highcharts().destroy();
```